# Matlab: variable values shows "error displaying values"

Tags: matlab

I have saved a number of output variable to .mat file. it showed its values in workspace properly. Unfortunately the variable values in workspace now show "error displaying values" instead of the appropriate size values that it showed previously. the same program i executed in another computer but there i could see the right values.

Comment: Did you redefin one of these functions: `char`, `disp`, `display`?

Comment: No,I havent changed any of those function

Comment: Are these saved variables of one of these types: user-defined class, graphic handle, file handle?

Comment: those are user defined

Comment: I guess that if you have "lost the definition" then matlab cannot display the variables. You have to "re-teach" matlab what your user defined class is before importing the variables; then it should be OK.